# Worksheet name from variable in Cell

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help here, I've this excel macro to set the target worksheet (or reference to a worksheet with the name of "sheet2"

> Set targetWS = Worksheets("sheet2")

My question is, what if I wanted to call out this "sheet2" from another worksheet with the name of "master", and the Cell A1, I have this sheet2 written there.

How should I rewrite my macro code for this case?

Set targetWS = ?

I've try many ways but still couldn't get it right. Can anyone help to shed some lights on this?

Thanks.

Comment: `Set CellA1Sheet2 = sheets("sheet2").range("A1")` ? Or.... `Set targetWS = Worksheets("sheet2")` ... then `set cellA1TargetSheet = targetWS.range("A1")`

Comment: Are these worksheets in the same workbook? If so, Is the code in this workbook? What are the number and description of the error occurring in findwindows's solution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Dim sh As String
Dim targetWS As Worksheet

sh = Worksheets("master").Range("A1")
Set targetWS = Worksheets(sh)
Debug.Print targetWS.Name
```

Comment: Thanks findwindow.. unfortunately, this is not working for me, error came out on Set targetWS = Worksheets(sh)   this line.

Comment: What's `sh`?...